# Switching the values of variables in C

Tags: c

I have this function called `void rotateLeft(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d)`. I want to give the variables a,b,c and d to this function. I want to call the function and then **a** needs to get the value of **b**, **d** the value of **a**, **c** the value of **d** and **b** the value of **c**. I have added my main code below where the function is being called and the code of the rotateLeft function. What do I put in the rotateLeft function to get it to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void rotateLeft (int*, int*, int*, int*); 

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int a,b,c,d,n;

    while( (n = scanf("%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d)) == 4)
    {
       rotateLeft(&a,&b,&c,&d); 
       printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
    }

}
```

rotateLeft function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rotateLeft(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d){




}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. What did you try? Come on! Don't expect us to do your work for you. You basically listed the code but in English ...

Comment: Well it's pretty difficult for me, I'm just a beginner with C.

Comment: The problem is not language specific, it's on the algorithm level.  You need to figure out an algorithm that can move the values into different variables without loosing one of the original values.  Understand the problem in "a = b; b = a;" and fix it, and then extend it to rotate more than just two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, maybe I'm being stubborn expecting more code in the question.

Here's how I would solve it:

```
void rotateLeft(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d){
  const int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = *c;
  *c = *d;
  *d = tmp; /* Because we've overwritten 'a', use a copy. */
}
```

Very straight-forward, I should hope.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! When placing the value of a variable into another variable u need to use a & right?

Comment: @Teuntje No, my code is correct. The `&` ("address of") operator is used to take the address of something, when working with pointers. That's why you use it with `scanf()` and `rotateLeft()`, those functions need pointers to the variables they should change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for swapping 2 variables. Try to adjust it to your problem.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp
}
```

Comment: I like this answer as it gives a foundation for how to approach this kind of problem without just outright giving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to allocate space for another temporary variable (for whatever reason), you can swap/rotate the values using the XOR operator. The XOR operator is sometimes called the [parity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function). This is more of an interesting fact than a practical application. The `rotate_left` function in the code below uses only 3 variables, but the principle can apply to any number of variables (look at the `rotate_right` function to see how the order of variables affects the output).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void number_swap(int* a, int* b) {
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}

void rotate_left(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    *a ^= *b ^ *c;
    *c ^= *a ^ *b;
    *b ^= *a ^ *c;
    *a ^= *b ^ *c;
}

void rotate_right(int* a, int* b, int* c, int* d) {
    *a ^= *b ^ *c ^ *d;
    *b ^= *a ^ *c ^ *d;
    *c ^= *a ^ *b ^ *d;
    *d ^= *a ^ *b ^ *c;
    *a ^= *b ^ *c ^ *d;
}

int main() {
    int a = 7894;
    int b = 1989;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    number_swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);

    int aa = 5;
    int bb = 8;
    int cc = 3;
    printf("aa = %d, bb = %d, cc = %d\n", aa, bb, cc);
    rotate_left(&aa, &bb, &cc);
    printf("aa = %d, bb = %d, cc = %d\n", aa, bb, cc);

    int aaa = 1;
    int bbb = 3;
    int ccc = 5;
    int ddd = 7;
    printf("aaa = %d, bbb = %d, ccc = %d, ddd = %d\n", aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd);
    rotate_right(&aaa, &bbb, &ccc, &ddd);
    printf("aaa = %d, bbb = %d, ccc = %d, ddd = %d\n", aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
a = 7894, b = 1989
a = 1989, b = 7894
aa = 5, bb = 8, cc = 3
aa = 8, bb = 3, cc = 5
aaa = 1, bbb = 3, ccc = 5, ddd = 7
aaa = 7, bbb = 1, ccc = 3, ddd = 5
```

You can run this example [here](http://ideone.com/ua19BB).

You can read more about why the XOR Swap Algorithm works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).